# Does Gauss flux theorem hold in relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, maxwell-equations, gauss-law

Does the Gauss flux theorem, stated in the classical electrostatics as $\iint{\vec{E}}\cdot{\vec{dS}}=q/\epsilon_0,$ hold in the case of relative motions. For instance if we observe a charged body with total charge Q moving with certain speed relative to us should we deduce that $\iint{\vec{E}}\cdot{\vec{dS}}=Q/\epsilon_0$?

My reasoning to believe it does hold even in the case of relative motions is that the charge is invariant and thus the total flux out of the boundary of the surface will be always Q independently of the observer's coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, I confused charge and charge density. So, you have an equality where the r.h.s. is invariant. So, after transforming the area of integration as well as the $\vec E$ on the l.h.s., the equality will still hold. Is that the question?

Comment: @Pekov note that the Gauss Law is one of the [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Conventional_formulation_in_SI_units), which are covariant. This means: the four Maxwell equations are true in special relativity, and in particular so is the Gauss Law.

Comment: Yes that was the question, thanks for the answers!